# C++: Repeat output i times without an explicit loop

Tags: c++

Is there is way to do so <strike>without a loop</strike> writing as less code as possible:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) std::cout << 'x';
```

Like in python:

```
print 'x' * 10
```

Comment: similar problem at geeks for geeks : http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/output-of-c-program-set-18-3/

Comment: Why would you believe that *10 in python does not involve a loop?  try foreach;

Comment: sorry, the question body was corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::generate_n(
    std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout, ""),
    10,
    [](){ return 'x'; }
);
```

Comment: Now that's clever.  Especially as it can easily be made to work with `std::string` instead of `char`.  The only drawback is that it doesn't return a string, if thats what you need.  (If the first argument is `std::back_inserter( myString )`, it will append to a `std::string`.)

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`std::string(size_t, char)` constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/):

```
std::cout << std::string(10, 'x');
```

Note that, unlike in Python, this only works with chars and not with strings.

Comment: Or just use `std::cout << "xxxxxxxxxx";` and be done with it ;)

Comment: I'd point out the smiley face at the end of my last comment, but something tells me it won't help.

Comment: @David Because there is no `std::string` constructor that accepts both a string and a "repetition count"?

Comment: It would be easy enough to write, however.  You could even overload the `*` operator, if you wanted (but since you're not allowed to put it in `std::`, you can't count on ADL picking it up).

Answer (score 3):

```
void print(const char *s, int n)
{
   if (n > 0) 
   {
      cout << s;
      print(s, n - 1);
   }
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean why not recursion? This is recursion.

Comment: recursion is not best option for c-like languages, but thanks

Comment: @NikBougalis - Where did that question come from (seems to lack context. Denis - this is a stupid question in the first place IMHO.

Comment: @EdHeal someone else had asked "why not use recursion?" in a comment that has now, apparently, been deleted. I guess I should delete my comment as well, since it does look out of place now.

Answer (score 1):

The most extensible/reusable way is to just create a function similar to Ed, above -- although I'd use a stringstream and not couple the function with the printing

IMO, NPE's answer is too restrictive by forcing it to be a single character only, and Ed's is more of a C answer than a C++ answer. As a side-benifit, the function also allows you to stream characters, integers, strings, etc.

```
template <class T>
std::string multiplyString(int count, const T &input)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
       ss << T;
    return ss.str();
}

int main(argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << multiplyString(10, 'x') << std::endl;
    std::cout << multiplyString(5, "xx") << std::endl;
    std::cout << multiplyString(5, 1234) << std::endl;
}
```

Best of luck

Comment: It's not really reasonable (or necessary) to use `std::ostringstream` for this.  You use `std::ostringstream` when you need to format something, not just concatenate.

Comment: agreed James -- good catch -- I had intended to make it a template so that you could stream anything as my comment originally said, but I left the input argument as a std::string which defeated the purpose of the stringstream.

Comment: But do you want to stream anything?  Remember that the original question concerned `*` (as in Python... and my pre-standard String class, which by a curious coincidence, was very, very close to Python's `string`).  You can't overload '*' for `int`.  And the results of your function on `int` would be unusable, because there is no separator.  And finally, isn't this just what `ostream_iterator` is designed for?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one else has offered a reasonable implementation:

```
std::string
multiplyStrings( int count, std::string const& original )
{
    std::string results;
    results.reserve( count * original.size() );  //  Just optimization
    while ( count > 0 ) {
        results += original;
    }
    return results;
}
```

Creating the overloads for `operator*` from this would not be
difficult.  Defining them in namespace std *would* be undefined
behavior, but IMHO, there's a reasonably good chance that you
could get away with it anyway.